# Why "either not $B$ or $C$" is logically equivalent to "$B$ implies $C$"?

Tags: logic

On the book it says " $\lor \neg BC$ can be written as $\implies BC$, which read as 'either not B or C' or 'B implies C' " but I don't really understand why they are logically equivalent. Thanks ahead!

Comment: That only works in boolean logic.  Write down their truth table and see for yourself.

Comment: You can just make a truth table for each and see that they are exactly the same.

Comment: @acarturk This is Polish notation, not reverse Polish.

Comment: Let $C$ mean: "You clean up your room." and $B$: "You may watch TV."  Now $C$ or not $B$ means: "Clean up your room or you aren't allowed to watch TV.", which is the same as "If you're allowed to watch TV, then you've cleaned up your room."

Answer (score 4):

\begin{array}{cc|cc}
B&C&B \to C & \neg B \lor C\\
\hline
T&T&T&T\\
T&F&F&F\\
F&T&T&T\\
F&F&T&T\\
\end{array}

Answer (score 2):

By definition, a conditional statement is true unless the premise is true and the conclusion is false.  Since the premise of $B \implies C$ is $B$ and the conclusion is $C$, $B \implies C$ is true unless $B$ is true and $C$ is false.

By definition, a disjunction of two statements is true unless both statements are false.  Thus, $\neg B \vee C$ is true except when $\neg B$ is false and $C$ is false.  If $\neg B$ is false, then $B$ is true.  Thus, $\neg B \vee C$ is true unless $B$ is true and $C$ is false.

Answer (score 1):

With De  Morgan's laws:

$B\implies C$ is false if there exists a counterexample, i.e. if $B$ is true and $C$ false – in other words if $B\wedge \lnot C$ is true. So $B\implies C$ is
$$\lnot(B\wedge\lnot C)=(\lnot B)\vee(\lnot(\lnot C)=(\lnot B)\vee C)$$

Answer (score 0):

In classical logic, an equivalent and more natural "definition" (using a more standard notation) would be

$$A\implies B\space\equiv\space \neg[A\land \neg B]$$

Perhaps you are confused about the actual meaning of "implies" in mathematics. $A$ 
 implies $B$ does *not* mean that $A$ causes $B$, or that $B$ causes $A$. There are no notions of cause and effect, or the passage of time in mathematics.

For any logical propositions $A$ and $B$ that are unambiguously either true or false at the moment, $A$ implies $B$ means simply that it is *not* the case that both $A$ is true and $B$ is false. For every other combination of truth values, the implication is true.

**Truth Table**

[image: Truth Table for a => b]

From the truth table, we see that:

- If $A$ is true and $B$ is true, then $A\implies B$ is true (line 1)
- If $A$ is true and $B$ is false, then $A\implies B$ is false (line 2)
- If $A$ is false, then $A\implies B$ is true regardless of the truth 
  value of $B$ (lines 3 and 4)
- If $B$ is true, then $A\implies B$ is true regardless of the truth 
  value of $A$ (lines 1 and 3)

Note: Although the above "defintiion" of IMPLIES is usually given as The Definition in introductory textbooks, it can also be derived from what might be called more "primitive" rules. See an example of such a derivation [here](https://www.dcproof.com/DeriveImplies.html). (Some knowledge of natural deduction is required.)